# Spring Batch decider without duplication

Tags: java, spring-batch

I have a case where I have a user input lets call it RunningMode. The input can have 3 possible states: STATE1, STATE2, STATE1_AND_STATE2.
The logic to implement is as follows if STATE1 is set then stepA should be executed if STATE2 is set then stepB should be executed and finally if STATE1_AND_STATE2 is set then I should run in parallel stepA and stepB.

I know how to solve this in an ugly way like this:

```
<batch:decision id="makeWorkFlowDecision" decider="myDecider"> 
                    <batch:next on="STATE1" to="stepA" /> 
                    <batch:next on="STATE2" to="stepB" />
                    <batch:next on="STATE1_AND_STATE2" to="stepC" />
</batch:decision>

<batch:split id="stepA" task-executor="taskExecutor">
<!-- content of stepA -->     
</batch:split>   
<batch:split id="stepB" task-executor="taskExecutor">
<!-- content of stepB -->     
</batch:split>    

<batch:split id="stepC" task-executor="taskExecutor">
<!-- content of stepA --> 
<!-- content of stepB -->     
</batch:split>
```

Like you can see there is duplication in stepC. I repeat content of stepA and stepB. Plus as far as I know in stepC stepA and stepB won't run in parallel.
Content of stepA and stepB consists of 2 flow blocks each in which I define steps. Is there a way to have conditional next on stepA ?

Answer (score 2):

Below is an example of what Luca is describing:

```
<flow id="flowA">
    <!-- stepA related steps here -->
</flow>

<flow id="flowB">
    <!-- stepB related steps here -->
</flow>

<batch:split id="stepA" task-executor="taskExecutor">
    <flow parent="flowA"/>
</batch:split>   
<batch:split id="stepB" task-executor="taskExecutor">
    <flow parent="flowB"/>
</batch:split>    

<batch:split id="stepC" task-executor="taskExecutor">
    <flow ref="flowA"/>
    <flow ref="flowB"/>
</batch:split>
```

Comment: the version of Spring Batch which I use does not allow to define abstract flows nevertheless thanks for the example I achieve similar results with steps nested within flow blocks.

Answer (score 1):

SB (as Spring is general) allow you to define [abstract step](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/configureStep.html#AbstractStep).
You can define abstract `stepA` and `stepB` and split using `parent` property (check [split-flow official documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/configureStep.html#split-flows) for example).